# Java Stream to aggregate list of JSONs into groups

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, for-loop, java-stream

I have list of objects in java, like this.

```
[
  {
    "applicationNumber": "100400",
    "users": "A",
    "category": "student"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "100400",
    "users":"B",
    "category": "student"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "100400",
    "users":"C",
    "category": "neighbour"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "100400",
    "users": "D",
    "category": "neighbour"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "200543",
    "users": "C",
    "category": "student"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "200543",
    "users": "A",
    "category": "student"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "200543",
    "users":"D",
    "category": "friend"
  }
]
```

I want to group users as list (order does not matter)  for each category for every applicationNumber. Can refer below json to get the idea.

```
[
  {
    "applicationNumber": "100400",
    "users": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "category": "student"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "100400",
    "users": [
      "C",
      "D"
    ],
    "category": "neighbour"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "200543",
    "users": [
      "C",
      "A"
    ],
    "category": "student"
  },
  {
    "applicationNumber": "200543",
    "users": [
      "D"
    ],
    "category": "friend"
  }
]
```

I am able to this using a for loop, HashMap and if else conditions. I want to use Java 8 stream to achieve the same . Can anyone help me , I am new to java.

PS: Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide some sample data in Java?

Comment: I don't have sample data as I am querying over DB  and storing it in a POJO.

Comment: Do you use MongoDB ? If yes you can achieve same by using the aggregation pipeline https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Comment: No, I am using Oracle db. to interact I am using jparepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using streams here is a little bit overengineering but you can to that in two steps. First you need to use `Collectors.groupingBy()` to group yours pojos into map of lists. Next you need to reduce each list to a single value by using `stream().reduce()`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
List<Application> applications = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, Application[].class));
List<Application> groupedApplications = applications.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ApplicationKey::of, Collectors.toList()))
        .values().stream()
        .map(apps -> apps.stream().reduce(Application::merge))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Application.java:

```
public class Application {
    private String applicationNumber;
    private String category;
    private List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Application merge(Application first, Application second) {
        assert ApplicationKey.of(first).equals(ApplicationKey.of(second));
        Application merged = new Application(first.applicationNumber, first.category, first.getUsers());
        merged.users.addAll(second.getUsers());
        return merged;
    }
    //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

ApplicationKey.java

```
public class ApplicationKey {
    private String applicationNumber;
    private String category;

    public static ApplicationKey of(Application application) {
        return new ApplicationKey(application.getApplicationNumber(), application.getCategory());
    }

    public ApplicationKey(String applicationNumber, String category) {
        this.applicationNumber = applicationNumber;
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ApplicationKey that = (ApplicationKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(applicationNumber, that.applicationNumber) &&
                Objects.equals(category, that.category);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(applicationNumber, category);
    }

    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can try `Collectors.collectingAndThen()` to do that in one step but I think that might be less readable.